# R how to filter lines where char number 20 = 'x'

Tags: r

what is the most efficient way to get this on a big file (2M rows).
I started to read text file like below, but bit confused with power of all R options  to filter only records where character number 20 equal to 'x'.
Thanks to all gurus,

```
z <- readLines("C:\\R\\STATS_2344_V1.txt")
```

Comment: or `z <- z[substr(z, 20, 20) == 'x']`

Comment: Tx much mt, so easy!! trying to modify it now to get negation to get where this char is not in [0-9]

Comment: Good luck. Let us know if you meet new trouble.

Comment: z [!(substr(z, 20, 21) >= 0 & substr(z,20, 21) <= 99)] # where char 20-21 NOT in 0-99 range

Comment: You have to convert it to numeric first. like `as.numeric(substr(z, 20, 21)) >= 0`

Comment: `not_a_number <- is.na(as.numeric(gsub("\\D","",substr(z, 20, 21)))) # we're ignoring the 2nd character if it's not a number`  then  `z[not_a_number]` to get your z where there's no number in these 2 characters

Comment: Tx much all again, for my case actually I will go with alpha , so I can  use " 0" and "99". I could have spaces in there .